# Keyboard and mouse doesn't work on HP EliteDesk 800 G2 mini

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I bought HP EliteDesk 800 G2 Desktop mini - 35W with Windows 10 and I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on it. But now my mouse and keyboard don't work outside of bios and grub. PC has only 6x USB 3 and not USB 2 or PS2. I even tried to install back Windows 10 and mouse, keyboard didn't work there too. BIOS settings didn't help either so I don't know what to do. Can somebody please help me.

Comment: If your mouse and keyboard don't work with either Ubuntu or Windows, it is not an OS level problem.

Comment: how they are connected to the computer? is it possible for you to try another keyboard? what model is the current keyboard?